# Modificar template name Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Estoy generando una view para busqueda de productos y quiero modificarla para tambien hacer busquedas por usurios cuando el nombre empiece por '@'.

Ahora mismo tengo esta view:

```
class BusquedaView(FilterView):
    model = Producto
    filterset_class = BusquedaFilter
    template_name = 'frontend/filtrado.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BusquedaView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.GET.get('nombre')[0] == '@':
            perfiles = Perfil.objects.filter(
                        usuario__username__istartswith = self.request.GET.get('nombre')[1:])
            context['perfiles'] = perfiles
        else:
            return context
```

En caso que introduzcan el caracter @ al principio modifique la variable `template_name` por otra template distinto en la que está la presentación de los usuarios.

No sé si hay alguna forma de hacer eso o directamente tendría que enviarla a otra URL en la que se le personalice la funcion `get_context_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar hacerlo sobreescribiendo el método `get` de tu clase:

```
# ...
from django.shortcuts import render


class BusquedaView(FilterView):
    model = Producto
    filterset_class = BusquedaFilter
    template_name = 'frontend/filtrado.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BusquedaView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        template_name = self.template_name
        nombre = request.GET.get('nombre')
        if nombre.startswith('@'):
            perfiles = Perfil.objects.filter(
                        usuario__username__istartswith=nombre[1:]
            )
            context['perfiles'] = perfiles
            template_name = 'mi_otro_template.html'
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Es sencillo, en `get_context_data()` no podrías hacerlo simplemente porque su función es la de construir el contexto (el diccionario), pero si lo haces desde el `get()` tienes la opción de cambiar el nombre del template ya que `get()` debe retornar un response (usando `render()` en este caso).

**Ojo:** Fíjate que estoy usando `startswith()` en vez de buscar la posición por su índice `0`. Es más seguro.

Comment: Por las pruebas que he hecho, se puede modificar el template_name en el get_context_data sin problema de la misma forma que lo haces tu en la función get(). Gracias sobre la función startwith(), me acababa de dar un error hace 5 minutos al pasarle la variable vacía.